# Understanding the number of Sockets opened by Users

Tags: 14.04, networking

I am using Netdata , Influxdb and Grafana to monitor my system. I saw in the networking section that the number(around 80) of sockets opened by user `"root"` are much higher than the other users.

The below image tells the data for past 15 minutes, and it usually remains same with very little variations.

Is Something wrong with my system OR this is usual on ubuntu systems ?
Moreover Is there any way I can see the sockets opened by users ?

Some extra info,

```
alphauser@AlphaServer:~$ sudo netstat nap | wc -l
228
alphauser@AlphaServer:~$ netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
22
```

[image]

Comment: `netstat` not only shows TCP/IP connections, but also Unix domain sockets, wich is the majority on my system. `netstat | awk '{print $1;}' | uniq -c` will show you how many sockets are open of each type.

Comment: yeah okay. If it shows unique, why Active and Proto both are written twice ? And also, any other helpful thing for my question ?

Comment: Active and Proto are shown twice, because the heading is shown twice. Once for "Active Internet connections" and once for "Active UNIX domain sockets". When you `sort` before `uniq`, you will see it as `2 Active`.